# Why bitcoin address instead of public key?

Tags: bitcoin, signing, public-key

In asymmetric encryption it is quite common to publish your public key to others. With the public key everyone can verify signatures created with the according private key.

So why do crypto-currencies like bitcoin not simply use the public key as the output of a transaction directly?

Bitcoin is instead using a so called [address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address). What is the reason instead of just using the curve25519 public key?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and would be better suited to Bitcoin.SE (where it is incidentally [already answered](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49158/why-do-you-use-bitcoin-addresses-instead-of-public-keys))

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two advantages to publishing an address, i.e., a RIPEMD-160 hash of the public key, instead of the public key directly:

- The hash is only 160 bits compared to 256 bits of public key, so we safe about 1/3 of the space that we'd use when directly using public keys. This is both data transferred and stored at the endpoints. While the transferred size is pretty clear, storage comes in two forms as well: UTXO set size and on disk size.
- Some limited protection against ECDSA being broken: should it become computationally feasible to create a signature given a public key, because of a weakness being discovered, we can avoid all funds being stolen by having this level of indirection. Assuming that it takes a while to generate a valid signature we can switch the signature algorithm, and the owners in possession of the private key still have a timing advantage w.r.t. an attacker, which would have to grab the public key from the wire, turn around and quickly compute a signature to a competing transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, to utilize the UTXO one does have to provide the public key and the signature. This IMHO in the end leads to even more wast of storage instead of using the public key in the first place. Please correct me if I am missing something. I understand the second point if you are using a keypair only once per transaction, however.

Comment: The difference is that the UTXO is a set that is maintained in memory, hence any savings that are done there reduces the overall memory footprint of the bitcoin daemon. Revealing the public key at spend time provides the verifying node with the necessary information to verify the correctness, and the transaction can be flushed to disk afterwards, hence not encumbering the in-memory UTXO, It is true that p2pkh is bigger than p2pk, but the location this information is stored is important in this case. In addition we can store only the public key after the spend instead of both hash and pubkey.